# Eclipse 4.4 Standard startup error

Tags: eclipse, aptana3

Just installed Eclipse Luna (4.4 Standard). From Help menu, installed Aptana plugin. After restarting the IDE, I get the following error:

An internal error occurred during: "Enable debugging and flush log cache".
org/eclipse/osgi/framework/internal/core/FrameworkProperties

It seems the environment works properly, but I get the error every time I open the program.

Here is the log:

> !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Enable debugging and flush log cache".
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/framework/internal/core/FrameworkProperties
>       at com.aptana.core.util.EclipseUtil.setPlatformDebugging(EclipseUtil.java:449)
>       at com.aptana.core.CorePlugin.enableDebugging(CorePlugin.java:110)
>       at com.aptana.core.CorePlugin.access$0(CorePlugin.java:97)
>       at com.aptana.core.CorePlugin$1.run(CorePlugin.java:83)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkProperties cannot be found by osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.aptana.core"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.3.0.1373665087"; singleton:="true"
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:406)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:326)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:318)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 5 more

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Development version of Aptana plugin seems to work fine with Eclipse Luna. Use this link for installation instead of stable one:

http://studio-jenkins.appcelerator.org/job/studio3-feature-development/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/

Use it with Eclipse Luna Standard Edition instead of Eclipse Luna for PHP developers. After installation switch to a Web perspective and configure as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Only try update the plugin Aptana from Eclipse. Restart the IDE eclipse and it should work.

Comment: This fixed it. The issue has been fixed in Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.6.0.201407100643

Comment: Indeed, this fixed it, but can't get rid of error markers. Doesn't happen with http://pydev.org/updates, only with Aptana3.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that Aptana is compatible with Eclipse 4.4? I suspect it is not, especially since 4.4 is still about 8 months from being released.

Comment: No I didn't check the compatibility. How can I get sure?

Comment: Unless it specifically says it supports Luna it almost certainly has not been tested with it yet. It looks like Aptana is being naughty and using an internal class which no longer exists in Luna.

Comment: 8 months later, Luna has been officially released, same error. A bit worrisome.

Comment: @mach try development version of Aptana

Answer (score 0):

copy http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

From the Help menu, select Install New Software... to open the Install New Software dialog.
Paste the URL for the update site into the Work With text box, and hit the Enter (or Return) key.
In the populated table below, check the box next to the name of the plug-in, and then click the Next button.
Click the Next button to go to the license page.
Choose the option to accept the terms of the license agreement, and click the Finish button.
You may need to restart Eclipse to continue.