# Missing toolbar button to Open Theme Preferences in latest Aptana studio plugin for Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I have installed the latest Aptana version 3.7.0 from

http://studio-jenkins.appcelerator.org/job/studio3-feature-development/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/

into eclipse Luna. I prefer this plugin version to the official stable one as it does not lead to an initial error in Eclipse. See [Eclipse 4.4 Standard startup error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672609/eclipse-4-4-standard-startup-error)

Comparing the available Aptana toolbar buttons in Window > Customize perspective to a previous installation of Aptana studio 3.4.2 into Eclipse Kepler I find that there is no button to "Open Theme Preferences" any more. Has the button been skipped intentionally or did I miss something?

Its no big deal - but I found it convenient to use this button as a shortcut to change the  present theme instead of using "Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes".

I checked this also for the official 3.4.2 plugin version - no toolbar button offered there, either.